# Where to put jenkins server in my situation

Tags: php, linux, git, jenkins, bitbucket

Hi i have a server setup like this ,
[image]

i want to update my QA server and Development server when ever a change happen to bitbucket . to automate this one person suggested me to use `git hooks` so i search about it and found about jenkins and bitbucket connector

[jenkins hook management](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Jenkins+hook+management)

so i think that i have to have a jenkins server somewhere and i can not figure out where .

where should i have a jenkins server . Inside Development server ? QA server ? or both servers  ?

Can anyone please help me and explain how to do this because i am new to jenkins and bitbucket

I using `PHP` and my servers using `LAMP`

Answer (score 1):

For what is worth, here is answer but not spectacular since there is no need to be spectacular :) You can set it up either on Development Server or QA Server it does not matter I guess.

Jenkins will orchestrate deployment from bitbucket to your environments and you just need one instance of it to do it. Flow will go something like this:

- Push to bitbucket
- Triggers commit hook
- Jenkins remotes and runs deployment script on development server
- Jenkins remotes and runs deployment script on QA server
- Jenkins runs tests on QA server
- etc.

Hope it helps, just to clarify deployment script here would be pull code, migrate db, restart server ...